# Adding Provisioned Concurrency for imported Lambda via cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

### Problem

I have `Lambda` function for which i want to add provisioned concurrency.I can access the `Lambda` only as a lower level `CfnFunction` resource or a `FunctionProxy` imported via ARN. I do not have access to the higher level `Function` construct in the `cdk` stack directly which would give me access to the needed attributes and methods to add prov. concurrency as usual.

### Details

My `cdk` stack setup consists of

- an `APIGateway REST API` running a `Lambda` function as request handler
- the `Lambda` request handler has no `Alias` or `Version` *(uses default `$LATEST`)*
- the `APIGateway REST API` and the `Lambda` function are created via [`cdk-chalice`](https://aws.github.io/chalice/tutorials/cdk.html) and not defined in my stack directly.
- this means they come from a pre-generated Cloudfomation template that gets then included into my main `cdk` stack template.
- so i have no higher level construct access to the `APIGateway` or `Lambda` function
- I only have lower level construct access *(`CfnFunction`)* from importing the [`Chalice`](https://aws.github.io/chalice/index.html) generated template back in the cdk stack or imported the `Lambda` function via `lambda.from_function_arn()`

### Question

- Is there a way to add provisioned concurrency

  - via manipulating the pre-generated Cloudformation template from `cdk-chalice`?
  - by importing the lambda through `lambda.from_function_arn()` then adding a `Version` and `ScalableTarget`?
  - via some tricks adding a `Version` from the lower level construct `CfnFunction`?
  - or maybe via some `AwsSdkCall`s to generate a `Version` for the lambda and add PC wrapped in a `AwsCustomResource`?

### What I have tried so far

#### Importing the Lambda

```py
# Pseudocode
handler = lambda.from_function_arn("arn-from-cdk-chalice-function")

# approach a - cdk deploy error: No current_version attribute on BaseFunctionImportProxy_
handler_version = handler.current_version

# approach b - cdk deploy error: Application Autoscaling cannot work with $LATEST
handler_version = handler.latest_version
target = appscaling.ScalableTarget(self, "ScalableTarget",
    service_namespace=appscaling.ServiceNamespace.LAMBDA,
    max_capacity=100,
    min_capacity=10,
    resource_id=f"function:{handler.functionName}:{handler_version.version}",
    scalable_dimension="lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency"
)
```